# better way to assign stored procedures output values from a table select

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Due to programming language restraints, my ERP system does not allow me to make advanced select queries, that´s why I need to rely on making a stored procedure on SQL Server, calling it from the ERP system and getting the result through an array.

The code belows works ok, but I think it´s not the correct way to assign the values to the output variables... I wanted to assign the output variables directly from the select, without need to make a #temp table... is it possible? or did I make it right?

If the code can be enhanced, I would gracefully accept any suggestions. The objective of the code is call a stored procedure with a RFID tag (read by a RFID card reader) and then get some employee info from another database, from another ERP, on another server (linked through SQL "linked servers")

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[KSBValTag] 
(
@rfid varchar(20),
@OUT_NUMCAD varchar(10) OUTPUT,
@OUT_NOMFUN varchar(50) OUTPUT,
@OUT_SIT varchar(2) OUTPUT,
@OUT_CODCCU varchar(5) OUTPUT,
@OUT_NOMCCU varchar(30) OUTPUT 
) as

Begin

    set @rfid = SUBSTRING(@rfid, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @rfid+'.'), LEN(@rfid))

    select fun.numcad as Numcad,
    fun.nomfun as Nomefun,
    fun.sitafa as Situacao,
    fun.codccu as CodCCU,
    ccu.nomccu as NomeCCU
    into #temp
    from [vetorh].vetorh.r034fun as FUN
    inner join
    [vetorh].vetorh.r018ccu CCU
    on fun.codccu = ccu.codccu
    where numcad = (select num_cartao from [ksb-app01].topacesso.dbo.Cartoes where CodigoDeBarras = @rfid)
    and tipcol = '1'

    set @OUT_NUMCAD = (select Numcad from #temp)
    set @OUT_NOMFUN = (select Nomefun from #temp)
    set @OUT_SIT = (select Situacao from #temp)
    set @OUT_CODCCU = (select CodCCU from #temp)
    set @OUT_NOMCCU = (select NomeCCU from #temp)

End
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select 
@OUT_NUMCAD = fun.numcad,
@OUT_NOMFUN = fun.nomfun,
@OUT_SIT = fun.sitafa,
@OUT_CODCCU = fun.codccu,
@OUT_NOMCCU = ccu.nomccu
from [vetorh].vetorh.r034fun as FUN
inner join
[vetorh].vetorh.r018ccu CCU
on fun.codccu = ccu.codccu
where numcad = (select num_cartao from [ksb-app01].topacesso.dbo.Cartoes where CodigoDeBarras = @rfid)
and tipcol = '1'
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I´ve tried something like this, but SQL Server was complaining about the syntax. Maybe I did something wrong. Very fast answer also, many thanks!

Comment: please at least add some explanation rather than just dumping some code.